# Is there anyone who knows how to locate javascript operation from which js file?

Tags: javascript, debugging

For example:

File `a.html` includes 5 javascript files. When I click the share btn (`<a href="" class="sns-share"></a>`) how can I know from which js file I have included that my click action came from.

Comment: Could you clarify? The small amount of code you have posted invokes no javascript function and the question doesn't make sense. Are you trying to find out which file a javascript function comes from? It might help if we knew why you didn't already know where the function was defined and why your script needs to find that out.

Comment: The page I need to he maintain is very confused, it includes more than 10 javascript files(already uglified). And I can not get the src file, now I need to modified a click operation. But I don not kown the operated code comes from which js file.

Comment: Are you maintaining some code and need to know where the a certain function is defined because its hard to tell from the page where it is?

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple possible situations. I will give each situation and how I would approach the problem.

### The button binds to the javascript:

This is the case where the button would be in the form `<a href="javascript:..."></a>` where the `...` is the function to call. In order for this to work, **the name of the function has not been uglified, even if the rest of the file has**. In this case, you should be able to open each of your 10 files in your favorite text editor and just search for that function name. Easy.

### The javascript binds to the button:

This is the case that I see as most likely given the tiny example you gave us. This is where the button is given some class (perhaps `sns-share`?) and the javascript is somehow looking for the button in the DOM and binding to its click event.

What I would do for this is similar to the above, with a couple extra steps. First, run each of your files through a "beautifier" (http://jsbeautifier.org/ is an example) to make them easier to read. **This won't fix variable names or anything like that; it only makes the structure easier to read**. Next, open the beautified files in your favorite text editor. Search for the class name that is used (in your case, this might be `sns-share`). Unless the code is deliberately obfuscated, **the class name string should show up somewhere**. Find this string, and intelligently read through the code, finding out where it is used. If you can find the spot where the javascript finds all elements with that class and binds a click handler to them, you have found your function.

The actual binding may take a couple different forms. Perhaps:

```
$(".sns-share").click(function () ....
```

if they are using jQuery. Or maybe:

```
var elements = jQuery(".sns-share");
elements.bind('click', function () ...
```

Maybe they didn't use any wrapper libraries and went with straight up DOM stuff:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('sns-share');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    element.onclick = function () ...
}
```

Or, something completely different if they are going for IE6 compatibility or something. You need to be on the lookout for what is going on.

### Note:

Either one of these processes depend on some things:

1. You are willing to read the code intelligently. You can't just blindly stare at it...you need to think about it what is doing.
2. The code hasn't been deliberately obfuscated. If this is the case, you're going to have a harder time finding where stuff is happening. In this case, I would just rewrite the entire program.

### Another note:

If it is the 2nd case above and you are having a hard time finding a place to start to look for the actual function being bound, you can inspect the element in Chrome (right click the button, select "Inspect element" and look at the Event Listeners (it should be in the panel on the left). Look for the click event and expand it. All functions listening for the click event will be shown there. If jQuery is used, this won't be of much help since it might be hard to find the function wrapped by the jQuery event, but *if they didn't use jQuery or something and bound directly to the DOM element*, this will point exactly to the function that is going to be executed.